# VSTS Build Not adding to drop folder

Tags: build, azure-devops, release, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need some help to determine why my VSTS build agent doesn't create an artifact in the drop folder

I have a solution that contains a website project (not a web application) and a logic project that i'm trying to build the website via VSTS. The build complete's correctly when i reference the solution as part of the "Process" step but nothing is added to the drop folder for the release process.

I have modified my build arguments to look for a publish profile that has been saved to the app_data/PublishProfiles (called vstsbuild) on the website project.  The website doesn't have a project file but it does have a website.publishproj file at the root of the website.

[image]

Any idea why it won't publish an artifact would be helpful

[VSTS Publish Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yJXgwzNn4__zm_sFbVI1WszVsUcYyr1b/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you see in the log files that your Web Deploy package is created? Do you have copy and publish steps in your build definition?

Comment: so looking at the logs for the build step i see that the solution builds with no errors.

Comment: 2017-11-14T16:53:10.1860488Z "d:\a\3\s\RewardCenter.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2017-11-14T16:53:10.1860488Z "d:\a\3\s\RewardCenter_2_.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
2017-11-14T16:53:10.1860488Z (Build target) ->

Comment: Can you show the whole build logs here? And can you share the project in one drive?

Comment: The complete log file would definitely help Can you share those?

Comment: I've added the link to the logs in the main question

Comment: @user1411081 There are a lot of warning for your project. You can add **NuGet task** (with command restore) before VS Buld task. And then what's the build log for VS Build step again?